# Modelsim/Questasim unit delay simulation

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, questasim

I would like to launch an unit delay RTL simulation using Questasim 10.1. I've looked how to compile the design and I see there is an option `+delay_mode_unit` for compiling `verilog` files. My design is `vhdl`.

Is there an option for this kind of design?

Answer (score 0):

By refering to [Modelsim 10.1c User Manual](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hadi/teaching/cs3220/doc/modelsim/ModelSim_Users_Manual_v10.1c.pdf)- `Chapter 7, Cell Libraries`, you can find how Modelsim can support various Verilog ASIC and FPGA cell libraries. Unit Delay Mode is explained one page after in the manual.

Concerning VHDL, I can't find a similar section where Modelsim has a confirmed support. However, in `Chapter 14, VHDL VITAL SDF`, you can find how to enable timing for VITAL cells only. You can read the following section `SDF to VHDL Generic Matching` for more help.

Also have a look at `Chapter 6, VITAL Usage and Compliance` on how to make a working setup for VHDL.